# Setting graphics variable from Image to HSBColor

Tags: c#, hsb

I'm trying to set the colour of g1 to HSBColor, I'm converting a Java program to run in c# so need someone to point me in the right direction.

```
 g1 = Graphics.FromImage(picture);
 g1 = Color.????
```

Below is the struct created for HSBColor:

```
public struct HSBColor
                {
                    float h;
                    float s;
                    float b;
                    int a;

                    public HSBColor(float h, float s, float b)
                    {
                        this.a = 0xff;
                        this.h = Math.Min(Math.Max(h, 0), 255);
                        this.s = Math.Min(Math.Max(s, 0), 255);
                        this.b = Math.Min(Math.Max(b, 0), 255);
                    }

                    public HSBColor(int a, float h, float s, float b)
                    {
                        this.a = a;
                        this.h = Math.Min(Math.Max(h, 0), 255);
                        this.s = Math.Min(Math.Max(s, 0), 255);
                        this.b = Math.Min(Math.Max(b, 0), 255);
                    }

                    public float H
                    {
                        get { return h; }
                    }

                    public float S
                    {
                        get { return s; }
                    }

                    public float B
                    {
                        get { return b; }
                    }

                    public int A
                    {
                        get { return a; }
                    }

                    public Color Color
                    {
                        get
                        {
                            return FromHSB(this);
                        }
                    }

                    public static Color FromHSB(HSBColor hsbColor)
                    {
                        float r = hsbColor.b;
                        float g = hsbColor.b;
                        float b = hsbColor.b;
                        if (hsbColor.s != 0)
                        {
                            float max = hsbColor.b;
                            float dif = hsbColor.b * hsbColor.s / 255f;
                            float min = hsbColor.b - dif;

                            float h = hsbColor.h * 360f / 255f;

                            if (h < 60f)
                            {
                                r = max;
                                g = h * dif / 60f + min;
                                b = min;
                            }
                            else if (h < 120f)
                            {
                                r = -(h - 120f) * dif / 60f + min;
                                g = max;
                                b = min;
                            }
                            else if (h < 180f)
                            {
                                r = min;
                                g = max;
                                b = (h - 120f) * dif / 60f + min;
                            }
                            else if (h < 240f)
                            {
                                r = min;
                                g = -(h - 240f) * dif / 60f + min;
                                b = max;
                            }
                            else if (h < 300f)
                            {
                                r = (h - 240f) * dif / 60f + min;
                                g = min;
                                b = max;
                            }
                            else if (h <= 360f)
                            {
                                r = max;
                                g = min;
                                b = -(h - 360f) * dif / 60 + min;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                r = 0;
                                g = 0;
                                b = 0;
                            }
                        }

                        return Color.FromArgb
                            (
                                hsbColor.a,
                                (int)Math.Round(Math.Min(Math.Max(r, 0), 255)),
                                (int)Math.Round(Math.Min(Math.Max(g, 0), 255)),
                                (int)Math.Round(Math.Min(Math.Max(b, 0), 255))
                                );
                    }

            }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to set g1 as hsbcolor?

Comment: Looks like you don't really know about [`Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.100).aspx) object. It is a tool that let's you interact with associated Bitmaps by providing a great number of methods for drawing, filling , transforming etc...  But if you have a Bitmap bmp you can get the color of a Pixel with `Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x,y);`

Comment: - If you want to convert it to a HSB structure you could use `GetHue`, `GetBrightness` and `GetSaturation`. The other way round need a conversion function.. No need for a `Graphics` object so far.. - So: What do you mean by _set g1 as hsbcolor_? What do you want to achieve?